# edit source code and adding navigate in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, react-navigation

I want to make a small change in the calendar code so that by clicking on every day of the week page ScanPhoto open up.
But I do not know how to do this.
My calculator is done correctly, but it's not

navigate ('ScanPhoto')
It has a syntax error and I do not know how to write

```
export default class Home extends Component<Props> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedStartDate: null,
    };
    this.onDateChange = this.onDateChange.bind(this);
  }

  onDateChange(date) {
    this.setState({
      selectedStartDate: date,
      navigate('ScanPhoto')
    });
  }


  render() {
    const { selectedStartDate } = this.state;
    const startDate = selectedStartDate ? selectedStartDate.format('jYYYY/jM/jD [is] YYYY/M/D') : '';

    const {navigate}=this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <Container>
      <Content>


      <View style={styles.container}>
      <JalaliCalendarPicker
      onDateChange={this.onDateChange}
      />

      <View>
      <Text >SELECTED DATE:{ startDate }</Text>
      </View>
      </View>



      <Button rounded light onPress={()=>navigate('calculator')}>
      <Text> calculator </Text>
      </Button>

      </Content>
      </Container>

    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your setState function in onDateChange has a syntax error. That you were trying to do there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For navigate to a new screen, you can use this code:

```
onDateChange(date) {
    this.setState({ selectedStartDate: date }) 
    this.props.navigation.navigate('ScanPhoto')
}
```

Comment: thaaaaaanks ^.^